# There are errors when I install django by git?

Tags: python, django

I install django through :

> git clone git://github.com/django/django.git
>
> pip install -e django/

I use Ubuntu 16.04.

But some errors occur :

```
Obtaining file:///home/leo/django
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/leo/django/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
        version = __import__('django').get_version()
      File "django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.utils.version import get_version
      File "django/utils/version.py", line 60, in <module>
        @functools.lru_cache()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /home/leo/django/
```

How to fix this ?
Thank you.

Comment: Why are you installing it from git and not with `pip install django`? It seems like you are trying to install it on Python 2 while the latest development version of Django requires Python 3.

Comment: yes,"pip install django" can fix my issue.But I just don't know why this issue happens?

Comment: Because you're trying to install it on Python 2, but the latest version of Django requires Python 3.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 39):

The last Django version does not support python 2.7.

If you really want to use python 2.7 and also use Django you should install a previous Django version.

The latest supported is: 1.11

Therefore, just run:

```
pip install django==1.11
```

Comment: This is not a real answer and it's all around for these kinda error! OP needs a way to install django 2 not an older version

Comment: Alex Who told you that he wants to install django 2? I doubt about your argument.

Comment: My name is also Alex and I'm ashamed of the other Alex's outburst. Your answer helped me, thanks. I need Python 2 because of some specialised packages I depend on.

Answer (score 16):

This because django version you have needs `python3` interpreter. so try to run the same command using `pip3`

To install `pip3`
`sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip`

then run

`pip3 install -e django/`

Comment: Django 2.0 was released in Dec 2017. For people using python 2.7, you can install an older version of Django by "pip install django==1.11.8" Go to https://www.djangoproject.com/download/ to check the latest release version number.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a Python 2 version of Django using git - you just need to checkout the correct release tag first. Try something like

```
git clone git://github.com/django/django.git
cd django
git checkout 1.11.0
cd ..
pip install -e django/
```

That said, you are much better off using pip directly, as other solutions suggest.

Answer (score -2):

```
Right > c:\Python27\Scripts>pip install django==1.11
Wrong > c:\Python27\Scripts>pip2.7 install django

c:\Python27\Scripts>pip2.7 install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\shyv\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-idpp6j\django\setup.py", line 32, in <module>
        version = __import__('django').get_version()
      File "django\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.utils.version import get_version
      File "django\utils\version.py", line 61, in <module>
        @functools.lru_cache()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\shyv\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-idpp6j\django\

c:\Python27\Scripts>pip install django==1.11
Collecting django==1.11
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cau
  SNIMissingWarning
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL co
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading Django-1.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9MB)
    100% |################################| 6.9MB 108kB/s
Collecting pytz (from django==1.11)
  Downloading pytz-2017.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (511kB)
    100% |################################| 512kB 922kB/s
Installing collected packages: pytz, django
Successfully installed django-1.11 pytz-2017.3
```