# How can the Python Image module be changed to address multiple versions of Django?

Tags: django, image, python-3.x, pip

When I pip install the Image module for Python 3, the installation works fine. When I pip install the Image module for Python 2, the installation breaks:

```
Collecting pyprel
  Downloading pyprel-2018.1.8.2203.tar.gz
Collecting Image (from pyprel)
  Downloading image-1.5.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy (from pyprel)
  Downloading numpy-1.14.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (16.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 16.9MB 79kB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: pyfiglet in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pyprel)
Requirement already up-to-date: shijian in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pyprel)
Collecting pillow (from Image->pyprel)
  Downloading Pillow-5.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (5.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.9MB 230kB/s 
Collecting django (from Image->pyprel)
  Downloading Django-2.0.tar.gz (8.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 8.0MB 154kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-DZf02T/django/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
        version = __import__('django').get_version()
      File "django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.utils.version import get_version
      File "django/utils/version.py", line 61, in <module>
        @functools.lru_cache()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-DZf02T/django/
```

This may be because recent Django versions may no longer supporting Python 2, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47746157/7558518). Is this actually the cause of the problem? I want to advise the relevant developers on what to do to fix the pip installation, perhaps by suggesting a Django version requirement, but I don't know how to do this. I would welcome guidance.

Comment: Django 2 does indeed not work for Python 2.

Comment: @Evert Yes, this appears to be the case. Do you know of a way to fix this particular installation procedure? A solution may be to require an older version of Django, but I do not know how to recommend this to developers.

Comment: To advise the developers, find either a repository with an issue tracker, or a contact address that you can use for filing issues. You can start your search at [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/).

Comment: By the way, what `image` package do you mean? I see `pyprel`, `image`, `numpy` and `django`. It's an odd package that would require these packages.

Comment: `Image` would be `PIL`, right? Install `Pillow` instead. And that should *not* require *any* of the above package (`numpy` at the most). You're doing something else.

Comment: @Evert No, Image is not PIL, it's a [Django application](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/image).

Comment: @BlandCorporation It's a bug in Image — they must not install the latest version of Django but install at most 1.11 for Python 2. Please send a pull request or report the bug at https://github.com/francescortiz/image

Comment: It's beyond me that a package for fancy printing requires Django. There is a fairly good chance that this is mistake in `pyprel`, and that they actually mean `Pillow`, since `PIL`/`Pillow` has a submodule `Image`, usually imported as `from PIL import Image` and used as such. That is a guess, but check with the the `pyprel` developers.

Comment: To add to my last comment: there's the line `image = Image.fromarray(data)` in the `pyprel` code, which indeed points to `PIL`/`Pillow` instead of that other image package. If I recall correctly, in the past, `Image` was also available as a direct import (and `pyprel` indeed contains `import Image`). With `Pillow`, that has become `from PIL import Image`. See the second warning on the  [Pillow installation documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.0.0/installation.html) (which all suggests `pyprel` is getting outdated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Django requirement is set loosely, you can probably circumvent it by installing Django first, with a specific version that works for Python 2, and then install `pyprel`.

For example:

```
python2.7 -m pip install django==1.11
python2.7 -m pip install pyprel
```

---

The cause of the problem is the fact that `pyprel` uses an outdated import (and, apparently, outdated name) of the `PIL` package (essentially replaced by `Pillow`), `Image`. That results in `pip` installing an `Image` package, while it actually should install `Pillow`.

The `import Image` in `pyprel` should also be changed to `from Pillow import Image` to work with current `Pillow` versions.

(The deduction that this is actually the `PIL`/`Pillow` package comes from the fact that there is an `Image.fromarray` line, a function that I can't find [`image`](https://github.com/francescortiz/image), but exists for `PIL`/`Pillow`).

There is no easy way out of this, other than filing an issue with the `pyprel` team, or downloading and altering the code yourself before installing. Because even with the above suggested installation, `pyprel` will likely run into problems at the `import Image` or `Image.fromarray...` line.

---

Note that this issue may also occur for Python 3. Installation may work, actually usage of `pyprel` may fail when encountering the above lines.

Comment: Thanks for this suggested solution. Unfortunately, this isn't working and I encounter the same problem. The `setup.py` of `pyprel` sets the dependences as `install_requires = ["Image", "numpy", "pyfiglet", "shijian"]`, so I don't think `pyprel` is the package that needs to change.

Comment: It may not be `pyprel`, but you're not showing what package you are *actually* trying to install that requires `django`. See also my other comment to your question.

Comment: I install `pyprel` in the above manner without problems. Not sure why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Django 2 does not support python2 at all.  A major part of the release was removing all python2 compatibility.

As you [can see in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django), Django 2 requires 3.4, 3.5 or 3.6

```
Django      Python
1.8         2.7, 3.2 (until the end of 2016), 3.3, 3.4, 3.5
1.9, 1.10   2.7, 3.4, 3.5
1.11        2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6
2.0         3.4, 3.5, 3.6
2.1         3.5, 3.6, 3.7
```